# Get value of xsi:type with xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, spring-integration, eai

I am trying to determine the correct XPath expression to return the value of the `xsi:type` attribute on the `Body` element.  I have tried what seems like everything without luck.  Based on what I read this would seem close but it is obviously not quire correct. Any quick guidance so that I can put finally to rest?

```
//v20:Body/@xsi:type
```

I want it to return `v20:SmsMessageV1RequestBody`

```
<v20:MessageV1Request>
    <v20:Header>
        <v20:Source>
            <v20:Name>SOURCE_APP</v20:Name>
            <v20:ReferenceId>1326236916621</v20:ReferenceId>
            <v20:Principal>2001</v20:Principal>
        </v20:Source>
    </v20:Header>
    <v20:Body xsi:type="v20:SmsMessageV1RequestBody">
        <v20:ToAddress>5555551212</v20:ToAddress>
        <v20:FromAddress>11111</v20:FromAddress>
        <v20:Message>TEST</v20:Message>
    </v20:Body>
</v20:MessageV1Request>
```

Comment: The Xpath expression looks good to me. Are you using this XPath in an XQUERY, an XSLT or something else? The most likely cause of a problem here is confusion caused by the namespace prefixes.  One way to eliminate namespaces as a source of confusion is to rewrite the xpath as this:  //*[local-name() eq 'Body']/@*[local-name() eq 'type']

Comment: Murray is right, because there are generally two ways to deal with namespaces in XPath - first: using `local-name()` and `namespace-uri()` XPath functions, second: using proper mechanisms of XPath engine - e.g. for standard JAXP you have to use properly configured NamespaceContext which maps prefixes to namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

As was pointed out in the comments, you have two choices:

1. Use `local-name()` to reference the target nodes without regard for namespaces
2. Properly register all namespaces with the XPath engine

Here's how to do the latter in Java:

```java
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NamespaceContext ctx = new NamespaceContext() {
    public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
        if ("v20".equals(prefix)) {
            return "testNS1";
        } else if ("xsi".equals(prefix)) {
            return "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
        }
        return null;
    }
    public String getPrefix(String uri) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    public Iterator getPrefixes(String uri) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
};
xpath.setNamespaceContext(ctx);
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//v20:Body/@xsi:type");       
System.out.println(expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING));
```

Note that I'm assuming the following namespace declarations:

```
<v20:MessageV1Request xmlns:v20="testNS1" 
                      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

You'll need to update `getNamespaceURI` to use the actual values.

Answer (score 0):

All great answers/feedback.  My actual issue seems have resolved itself with a night away and fresh build in the morning.  I will be enhancing with the feedback.  Thanks all.